# Google slides copy object 'with' its animations

Tags: google-slides, copy-paste, animations

I want to copy some objects with animations to another slide 'with' their animations. But I am not sure how to do that. If I copy the objects (ctrl+c) from one slide and paste them into another slide (ctrl+v) of the same file, the animations of the objects do not get copied. This is a bit annoying. I wonder if anybody has any suggestions regarding how to do this.

One workaround I found is that I can duplicate the slide with the animated objects and copy all the things from another slide and paste them into the duplicated slide. This workaround gets the job done, but this way is very time-consuming. I hope there is an easy way to copy objects 'with' their animations.

Google slides already lacks some basic features (e.g. [Is there a way to change the default Google Slides animation?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88398)). So, I am thinking of switching to the good-old MS-PowerPoint because of such annoyance, unless I find solutions to annoying problems I am having with google slides.